# Swift: How do I prevent users from navigating back to the root viewController when they are not authenticated?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, navigation, storyboard

I have a root viewController that is the main viewController that users can navigate to when they have been authenticated. Right now, when the app loads the root viewController, it checks if the user is logged in and navigates to the login viewController if the user isn't authenticated.

The problem is I don't know how to prevent the user from returning to the main viewController without authenticating. Right now, they are able to return via back button if I use `Show`, or by gesture if I use `Present Modally` or `Show Detail`. I have searched for hours and haven't found the answer to this problem. It would be easy if I could just remove the root viewController instance with something like `finish()` like in Android, and then create a new one once the user logs in but I'm not sure if that's even possible. How can I solve this?

Here is the code that presents my LoginViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    if (!isUserSignedIn()) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "pairedDevicesToLogin", sender: self)
    }
        
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: You probably need to restructure the way you manager your view controller. Before you present your initial view controller, check if they are authenticated. If not, then push your authentication view controller. Once they are authenticated, push your normal root view controller and remove the authentication controller from the navigation comtroller stack so they can't go back to it. If the initial check shows that they are already authenticated then proceed as you do now.

Comment: @Paulw11 Where would I write the code to check for authentication? In my NavController?

Comment: You would write it where you present your root navigation controller. This would probably be in your app delegate or scene delegate depending on which you are using.

Comment: Please share with us more code snippet.There is a lot of things you can do. As mentioned above you make an if, else statement in the scene delegate. Or you can block the back button on the sign in view until the user is authenticated. 'willMove' you have to use for that.

Comment: It’s easy to make a modal non dismissible. Show us the code that opens the login view.

Comment: @Darren, what do you mean by non-dismissible? I have added the code that opens the login view to my question.

Comment: Use the prepareForSegue method to make the destination a modal. I’m away from computer right now.

Comment: @Darren the destination is already being presented Modally. I created the segue in the storyboard editor and changed the setting to "Present Modally". Is that the same thing?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your comments. They helped me to find out that with iOS 13 and on, the auth code should be put in SceneDelegate as opposed to AppDelegate. After adding it there, it completely fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with navigation flow for authentication in iOS this is what worked for me.

With iOS 13 and later, authentication code should go in SceneDelegate instead of AppDelegate like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
    _ = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if ((user) != nil) {
            self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myMainViewController")
        } else {
            self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController")
            }
        } 
    }
```

This will allow the app to decide what viewController to load first based off of the authentication results.